# Discussion in UserStory via Rally REST API

Tags: java, rally

I tried read Discussion from User Story

```
    RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(new URI(rallyURL), userName, userPassword);
    restApi.setApplicationName("QueryExample");

    try
    {

        QueryRequest storyRequest = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
        storyRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name", "Owner", "UserName", "EmailAddress", "Discussion"));
        storyRequest.setLimit(1000);
        storyRequest.setScopedDown(false);
        storyRequest.setScopedUp(false);
        storyRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
        storyRequest.setProject(projectRef);
        storyRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "US4"));

        QueryResponse storyQueryResponse = restApi.query(storyRequest);
        JsonObject storyJsonObject = storyQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();

        System.out.println("Name: " + storyJsonObject.get("Name"));
        JsonObject userObject = storyJsonObject.get("Owner").getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject();
        System.out.println(userObject.get("UserName"));
        System.out.println(userObject.get("EmailAddress"));
        System.out.println(userObject.get("Discussion"));

    }
    finally
    {
        //Release resources
        restApi.close();
    }
```

Discussion is NULL.

How I can read and write Discussion for User Story via REST API?

WBR, Slava

Answer (score 0):

As long as you get the story, you may traverse it to Text attribute on a ConversationPost, which is an element of Discussion collection as follows:

```
int numberOfPosts = storyJsonObject.get("Discussion").getAsJsonArray().size();
            System.out.println(numberOfPosts);
            if(numberOfPosts>0){
                for (int i=0;i<numberOfPosts;i++){
                    System.out.println(storyJsonObject.get("Discussion").getAsJsonArray().get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("Text"));
                }
            }
```

Also, these fields need to be fetched:

```
storyRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name","Discussion","ConversationPost","Text"));
```

Here is the entire code:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.rallydev.rest.RallyRestApi;
import com.rallydev.rest.request.QueryRequest;
import com.rallydev.rest.response.QueryResponse;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.Fetch;
import com.rallydev.rest.util.QueryFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class aRESTstories {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {


            String host = "https://rally1.rallydev.com";
            String username = "user@co.com";
            String password = "1984";
        String workspaceRef = "/workspace/1111";
            String projectRef = "/project/2222";            

            String applicationName = "RESTExample: find story, print discussions";
            String wsapiVersion = "1.43";

        RallyRestApi restApi = new RallyRestApi(
                new URI(host),
                username,
                password);
        restApi.setApplicationName(applicationName); 
        restApi.setWsapiVersion(wsapiVersion);
        System.out.println(restApi.getWsapiVersion()); 

        try{
            QueryRequest storyRequest = new QueryRequest("HierarchicalRequirement");
            storyRequest.setFetch(new Fetch("Name","Owner","UserName","PlanEstimate","Discussion","ConversationPost","Text"));
            storyRequest.setLimit(1000);
            storyRequest.setScopedDown(false);
            storyRequest.setScopedUp(false);
            storyRequest.setWorkspace(workspaceRef);
            storyRequest.setProject(projectRef);
            storyRequest.setQueryFilter(new QueryFilter("FormattedID", "=", "US359"));

            QueryResponse storyQueryResponse = restApi.query(storyRequest);
            JsonObject storyJsonObject = storyQueryResponse.getResults().get(0).getAsJsonObject();
            String storyRef = storyJsonObject.get("_ref").toString();
            System.out.println("Name: " + storyJsonObject.get("Name"));

            int numberOfPosts = storyJsonObject.get("Discussion").getAsJsonArray().size();
            System.out.println(numberOfPosts);
            if(numberOfPosts>0){
                for (int i=0;i<numberOfPosts;i++){
                    System.out.println(storyJsonObject.get("Discussion").getAsJsonArray().get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("Text"));
                }
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception occurred....");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            restApi.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I have an error.. I'm edited your answer

Comment: @VyacheslavYanyuk don't edit posts to report problems with them - add the problem as comment, so that it can be addressed in the answer!

Comment: I don't see an edit, and verified it's working. What did you have to correct to make it work for you?